# How to replace " with \" in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a textbox that posts info to the server and it's in JSON format. Lets say I want to enter two quotes for the value, and the JSON struct would look like:

```
{
    "test": """"
}
```

I need it to look like:

```
{
    "test": "\"\""
}
```

so it will follow JSON standards and can be parsable/stringifyable.

I tried using

```
 var val = myVal.replace('"', "\\\"");
```

but this didn't work. `val` ends up with only one escaped quote like so `\""`Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does "this didn't work" mean? _What_ didn't work? What happened? Show us [a testcase](http://sscce.org/) to work with.

Comment: should't you do the conversion before you put data in JSON?

Comment: what do you  want to do with the escaped string?

Comment: Textboxes don't "post" anything on their own. And you haven't been clear about how your interface is used. Does your script build a JSON string? Does the user enter all of it? Show us your code.

Comment: Cut me some slack, I had to rush to get to a meeting on time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My answer makes some assumptions, as I've had to fill in the rather sizeable gaps in your question:

- The user will enter a text string into a textbox;
- Your script will read the textbox contents, and use those contents as the *value* of one of the items in a JSON string that it's building;
- The script sends this resulting JSON string to the server somehow.

If I've got that right, let's proceed...

---

### Baseline code

So, with some placeholders, you're doing:

```
function get_contents_of_textbox() {
   // Dummy data for example
   return 'My mum pushed and I said "Hello World"!';
}

function send_to_server(json_str) {
   // Dummy action: display JSON string
   console.log(json_str);
}

var myVal = get_contents_of_textbox();
var JSON  = '{ "test": "' + myVal + '" }';
send_to_server(JSON);
```

#### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EgKzs/), showing the malformed JSON.

---

### Initial attempt

To ensure that `JSON` is valid, *escape* any quotes and backslashes that it may contain. You already gave it a go:

```
myVal = myVal.replace('"', "\\\"");
```

and [the result of your attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/xqyCp/) is:

```
{ "test": "My mum pushed and I said \"Hello World"!" }
```

Only the first quote has been escaped. This is because only one instance of the search string is replaced by default.

The Mozilla documentation [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> To perform a global search and replace, either include the g flag in
>   the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include
>   g in the flags parameter.

---

### Working attempt

Unfortunately, the `flags` parameter is non-standard, so let's switch to the regex version of `replace`, and use the `/g` switch in it:

```
myVal = myVal.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

<sup>(You'll notice that I also condensed the replacement string, for brevity.)</sup>

Result:

```
{ "test": "My mum pushed and I said \"Hello World\"!" }
```

#### [Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/NY9jy/) Hurrah!

---

### Complete solution

Let's also add logic to escape backslashes, and we end up with this:

```
function get_contents_of_textbox() {
   // Dummy data for example
   return 'My mum pushed [a back\\slash] and I said "Hello World"!';
}

function send_to_server(json_str) {
   // Dummy action: display JSON string
   console.log(json_str);
}

var myVal = get_contents_of_textbox();
myVal = myVal.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'); // escape backslashes
myVal = myVal.replace(/"/g, '\\"');   // escape quotes

var JSON  = '{ "test": "' + myVal + '" }';
send_to_server(JSON);
```

Result:

```
{ "test": "My mum pushed [a back\\slash] and I said \"Hello World\"!" }
```

#### [Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/czs4S/)

Answer (score 7):

Use this

```
var val = myVal.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: One `replace` and three backslashes in second argument. :)

Comment: @Darcy: My answer points out some other considerations that you need to make. It also _explains_ the problem. Be sure to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a JS array

```
var arr = {
   test: '""'
}
```

and let the JSON interface handle the escaping for you. You shouldn't ever have to deal with the details yourself.

Comment: I think there's more going on here, but can't be sure until the OP expands on what he's doing.

Comment: (Also, **this is not an array**. Please stop propagating that rubbish.)

Comment: @Tomalak took my a long time to realise JSON and javascript objects were actually different things...

Comment: Also, agreed, that's not an array!  It's an object.  @Marc B arrays use [] not {} and are only numerically indexed in JS.  Objects just have the nice functionality of allowing array style access.

Comment: @Endophage: But I bet you feel great now that you know! :D

Comment: I've decided to downvote. There's no indication that there's any "JSON interface" here. I'm sure now that the OP is just building a JSON string.. and this is _not_ the same thing as a Javascript object.

Comment: @Tomalak. You are right I was building a JSON string. Sorry for the confusion, I had to rush to a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you're getting the string from a textbox you don't need to do anything to it to get it back to the server.  If you get the value of the textbox via jQuery's `$()` notation or pure `document.getElementById` it will already be properly escaped.  JavaScript doesn't take the value of your textbox and try to put it in quotes.

If you text box has `""` entered into it, `document.getElementById('mytextbox').value` is not equal to `"\"\""`.  The backslashes are only necessary when you are defining a string literal.

Try removing all your escaping and regex replacing and just send back the data from the text box without doing anything to it.  Your json should look something like:

```
{
    "test" : document.getElementById('myTextBox')
}
```